# WPF C# application, .xaml file error. Missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a few similar errors in my .xaml files. 
Here is the error message:
The type 'vm:MainViewmodel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Can anybody help me?

> ```
>          xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GoogleMap.ViewModel" 
>          x:Class="GoogleMap.App"
>          StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">  
> <Application.Resources>
>     <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
>     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
> </Application.Resources>     </Application>
> ```

Comment: In your view project, within Solution Explorer, did you add a reference to your view model project? If so, do you have a view model with that namespace and name?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Bob Horn! This error have been solved :)

Comment: The error came back again. I have the reference needed and the namespace is matched. I wonder where have gone wrong...

Comment: When I've experienced problems coming and going, it's been the result of one of the projects targeting .NET 4 Client Profile. When I change it to .NET 4, it works. Is that possibly it?

Comment: There is no difference compared to the Client Profile.. It's alright :)